# Rails Using REVERSE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have the following in my Rails 3 app photo view:

```
<% for version in @photos.first.versions.reverse %>
 .
 .
```

What's interesting is that on my local machine, it works as hoped by outputting (<%= version.version %>)

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

But on Heroku it's backwards

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is this a Heroky gotcha or maybe reverse is buggy? thanks

Comment: Whats your `has_many` declaration for `versions` does it contain an order clause? The order you are getting is possibly a fluke?

Comment: @Zabba, versions is powered by the acts_as_versioned gem. in the model I have "acts_as_versioned" and then in the view I call it by adding .versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the Ruby version.  I've had the same issues and attributed the problem to the fact that Heroku uses PostgreSQL, while in development I use SQLite. I also think it's specifically related to how Postgres orders objects when being called through an association. So the order would be the same for

```
Photos.all
```

but different for

```
Photos.first.versions.all
```

What I ended up doing was to use default scopes for some of the models so that they are always ordered in a defined way.

Be careful with default_scope, though. If you try to apply another ordering scope to a model that has a default_scope specifying an order, the the default_scope order will take precedent. I think patches are being worked on for this. But until then, you have to use 'unscoped'

```
default_scope order('created_at ASC')
scope :recent, unscoped.order('created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Thanks manually sorting first to normalize the query across platforms did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have had stuff that is different on local and production, on hosts such as heroku, and I think it's mainly about the ruby version but I usually just want to fix stuff and hack till I get a fix.

What I can tell you is that you might need to add `!` to your reverse method because you are not setting any variables here.

```
<% for version in @photos.first.versions.reverse! %>
```

Comment: Thanks, what does that do? (Tried it. didn't have any effect.

Comment: the `!` applies the change inline